# insertar campo por defecto en una fila de postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Les comento mi problema, resulta que estoy trabajando con NestJS para tener mi servidor backend, el cual hace muchas operaciones a una BD en postgres.

Lo que estoy haciendo es que al insertar un registro en una tabla X, el campo create_date se lo estoy delegando directamente a mi BD, por lo tanto agregué un campo "default" el cual mete un current_timestamp

Mi problema es que la hora que está insertando esta 1 por debajo de la hora real de mi pais por lo que no esta funcionando como debería estar funcionando

Así esta definido el campo actualmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es la data que ingresa cuando inserto algo en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice antes fue cambiar el tipo de dato a timestamptz pero el formato que guarda no me gusta, es como YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.sss-[algo]

**Hay forma de mantener el formato de la 2da imagen pero que respete mi zona horaria?**

**La unica forma es cambiandole el tipo de datos a timestamptz?**

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La hora en el servidor donde corre PostgreSQL está entonces, una hora por debajo de la hora en tu país.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por la respuesta. Hay alguna forma de modificar esa hora del servidor de postgres que indicas? finalmente opté por cambiar todas mis tablas a timestamptz, pero si puedo aprender ahora a cambiar la hora que toma postgres por defecto genial